# Given 2 vectors in 3d find a condition that satisfies an inequality.

Tags: vectors, 3d

given $u=[1, 0, 1]$ and $v=[1, 2, -1]$. Let $x = sv + t\sqrt{2} \ u \times v$, where $s ∈ R$ and $t ∈ R$. Find the condition on $s$ and $t$ that renders $||x|| \leq \sqrt6$. Answer should be a relation between $s ∈ R$ and $t ∈ R$. I'm not sure if my calculation is correct. i found the cross product of $u$ and $v$ and it's norm and the norm of $v$ and substituted it into the formula and got $s^2 + t^2 \leq 1$. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Moreover, while you edit your post to improve formatting, can you please also include your intermediate calculations? (My final result is not exactly the same as yours.)